# Some unpublished notes of Hofstadter

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, continued-fractions, integer-sequences

I'm looking for some unpublished notes called "Eta Lore," which are apparently related to a talk Douglas Hofstadter first gave at the Stanford Math Club in 1963. I know these notes exist because they're cited in the following articles:

- Hendel, R.J.; Monteferrante, S. "[Hofstadter's Extraction Conjecture](http://www.fq.math.ca/32-2.html)." The Fibonacci Quarterly 32(2), 1994.
- Chuan, W. "[Extraction Property of the Golden Sequence](http://www.fq.math.ca/33-2.html)." The Fibonacci Quarterly 33(2), 1995.
- Nillsen, R.; Tognetti, K.; Winley, G. "[Bernoulli (Beta) and integer part sequences](http://www.austms.org.au/Bernoulli)." A teaching module developed by the Australian Mathematical Society.

I've e-mailed the authors of the articles above, but I also thought I'd try asking around here, since none of the authors who've responded so far have been able to help. Any information on alternative references would also be appreciated.

**Motivation and Background**

I'm specifically interested in the definition of the function INT mentioned in Section I.33 of *Gödel, Escher, Bach*. The description there, in case it rings any bells, is: "The basic idea behind INT is that plus and minus signs are interchanged in a certain kind of continued fraction."

As far as I can tell, the notes I'm looking for are mostly about continued fractions and integer sequences---in particular, things called $\eta$-sequences and $\beta$-sequences (unfortunately, I have no idea what those are, and I haven't found any leads on [OEIS](http://oeis.org/)).

Comment: Have you contacted Hofstadter? He is alive and working: http://www.cogs.indiana.edu/people/homepages/hofstadter.html

Comment: The link should be updated to http://cogs.indiana.edu/people/profile.php?u=dughof

Comment: @DavidSpeyer, thanks for the suggestion! It should have been obvious, but wasn't to me at the time. I did get in touch with Hofstadter, and he send me a copy of the notes. (I'm sorry this thank-you was so long in coming, by the way---I completely forgot I'd asked this question, and was only reminded when it popped up on the front page again.)

Comment: @Vectornaut Can you send me his notes too?

Comment: @Vectornaut (or Alexey) Could either of you forward it to me as well?

Comment: @AlexeyUstinov, sent! (Subject line: 'Hofstadter's unpublished notes: "Eta-Lore"'.) If you don't get them for some reason, let me know.

Comment: @GregZitelli, sent also (see above).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This graph is looks like a graf of the function which replaces partial quotient (in *nearest integer continued fraction*) in the following way: $$a_i+~\leftrightarrow~a_i+1-.$$
For example
$$0+\cfrac{1}{3-\cfrac{1}{4+\cfrac{1}{5+0}}}\leftrightarrow
1-\cfrac{1}{2+\cfrac{1}{5-\cfrac{1}{6-0}}}.
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2+0}&\leftrightarrow1-\frac{1}{3-0}=\frac{2}{3},&\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{3+0}&\leftrightarrow1-\frac{1}{4-0}=\frac{3}{4},\\
\frac{2}{5}=\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+0}}&\leftrightarrow1-\frac{1}{3-\frac{1}{3-0}}=\frac{5}{8},&\frac{3}{5}=1-\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{2+0}}&\leftrightarrow
0+\frac{1}{3-\frac{1}{3-0}}=\frac{3}{8}.
\end{align*}
The picture from the book:
[image: Picture]

Answer (score 11):

A copy of Hofstadter's paper is on OEIS here: [Link to Eta-Lore paper](https://oeis.org/A006336/a006336_1.pdf)

It is also referenced on OEIS at A001468.